# Query for Dedit/Credit Transactions

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is Query I am using :

```
select Date2,  
       sum(case when Type='Debit' then Amount else 0 end)as DebitAmount,  
       sum(case when Type='Credit' then Amount else 0 end)as CreditAmount,  
      ((sum(case when Type='Debit' then Amount else 0 end))-sum(case when Type='Credit' then Amount else 0 end)) as Balance 
from MainTransaction 
group by MainTransaction.Date2 
order by Date2
```

OutPut :

```
Date       | Debit   | Credit | Balance
-----------+---------+--------+-----------
2015-02-10 | 0.0     | 0      | 0.0
2015-02-12 | 19200.0 | 0      | 19200.0
2015-03-01 | 62000.0 | 0      | 62000.0
2015-03-08 | 999.0   | 0      | 999.0
2015-03-09 | 10064.0 | 0      | 10064.0
```

What I want it to display total balance as well , I mean like date is `11.03.2015` it will also display total debit till date `11.03.2015` -credit till date `11.03.2015`..
What should I do .. I simply can't do sum as I am using group by date2..

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to do. Can you post input data, schema & expected output?

Comment: In `sqlLite` finally make a sql, can you check it, plz?

Answer (score 0):

Set {0} = '2015-03-11'

```
select ifnull(mt.Date2, mt.Date2s), 
    sum(case when mt.Type='Debit' then mt.Amount else 0 end)as DebitAmount,  
       sum(case when mt.Type='Credit' then mt.Amount else 0 end)as CreditAmount,  
       ((sum(case when mt.Type='Debit' then mt.Amount else 0 end))-sum(case when mt.Type ='Credit' then mt.Amount else 0 end)) as Balance 
from (
    select mt.*, sd.*
    from MainTransaction as mt
        left join 
        (select {0} as Date2s) as sd On mt.date2 = sd.Date2s
    where mt.date2 < {0}
    union all
    select mt.*, sd.*
    from (select {0} as Date2s) as sd
        left join 
        MainTransaction as mt On mt.date2 = sd.Date2s
    where mt.date2 is null
    ) as mt
group by ifnull(mt.Date2, mt.Date2s)
order by ifnull(mt.Date2, mt.Date2s)
```

Comment: Just a minor comment, no dbms is specified and you are using product specific functionality (isnull, square brackets etc.) Maybe you should inform OP which dbms this is for?

Comment: Can u please modify it according to mysql or sqlite?

Comment: I found `isnull` should become `ifnull`

Comment: My Bad achurally i am using Sqlite .. and 99% of Mysql queires work in it so i often ask for mysql.. i am getting following error

Comment: [09:51:56] Could not commit view changes. Error message: RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported

Comment: What i want is like Date 1  Crbal Drbal  drbal-bal    totalbal  then  totalbal on date2 must include TotalBal of date 1 like in bank statement.. i hope you now understood what i mean

Comment: plz, change your output in question to that you mean.